# Select newest test run with Automator script

Tags: xcode, applescript, xcode9, automator

I'm trying to select the newest test result in Xcode with Automator. It will always be below "Running tests" or "Pending". But the thing is, I'm not able to select anything from the navigator. Please see the information below :-).

[image]

This is the data I have from the Accessibility Inspector.

[image]

My current script:

```
use application "System Events"

tell application "Xcode" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    ## Show Report Navigator
    keystroke "9" using command down
    tell application "Xcode" to activate
    tell process "Xcode"
        tell (first text whose value contains "Today") to click it
    end tell

## Hide Navigator
#keystroke "0" using command down
end tell
```

The error:

[image]